# Effect of nested @tf.function calls on computation graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Consider the following code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
  
@tf.function
def inner(tensor):
    tf.print(tensor)

@tf.function
def outer(tensor):
    tf.print(tensor)
    inner(tensor)

tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.int32)

writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('logs/outer')
tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True)

outer(tensor)

with writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.trace_export(name='outer', step=0)
```

When I inspect the computation graph in tensorboard, it looks as follows:

[image]

Notice that inner is represented by a `StatefulPartitionedCall`. Then there's another thing in the tensorboard output, which I theorize is the actual op instantiation of `inner` but that doesn't have an apparent tie to the `StatefulPartionedCall`.

[image]

What are the conclusions of this? Do inner and outer both get separate computation graphs? Can I be confident that inner is still executing graph style (my empirical testing says yes). Is there a performance hit from not having it all inline in a single graph, or is it all effectively still in a single graph?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When you create a `tf.function`, you are creating a new graph for the operations within that function. All computed tensors then belong to this created graph an can only be accessed if returned from the `tf.function`, irrespective of inner/outer graph relationship (under normal use anyway - there are ways to capture tensors from an outer graph).

The following snippet demonstrates that for each `tf.function` in your example, a separate `tf.FuncGraph` is created.

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def inner(tensor):
    g = tensor.op.graph
    print(f"In inner tf.function, we have graph {g} named {g.name}. "
          f"The graph {g.name} has {g.outer_graph} as it's outer graph, "
          f"which is named {g.outer_graph.name}.")

@tf.function
def outer(tensor):
    inner(tensor)

    g = tensor.op.graph
    print(f"In outer tf.function, we have graph {g} named {g.name}. ")

tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor([1, 2, 3], dtype=tf.int32)
outer(tensor)
```

Running the above will give you the following output (modulo `id`, of course).

```
In inner tf.function, we have graph FuncGraph(name=inner, id=5173956128) named inner. The graph inner has FuncGraph(name=outer, id=5172536368) as it's outer graph, which is named outer.

In outer tf.function, we have graph FuncGraph(name=outer, id=5172536368) named outer.
```

Comment: Last question was: "Is there a performance hit from not having it all inline in a single graph, or is it all effectively still in a single graph?". From your answer I can conclude that there is no performance hit?

Comment: It should not incur a performance hit, no. In fact, if you enable XLA (`jit_compile=True`), then it may actually help with the clustering and fusion of ops. However, this is something that shouldn't be assumed. Every graph is different and it's sometimes best to go with what is empirically best, or what yields the best performance when analysing  GPU utilisation (if appropriate); kernel execution time should always be longer than kernel launch time etc.